# Google app engine can requests fail while shifting traffic to the new version?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am just wondering that as when I deploy my NodeJs app to new version on App Engine, now the traffic gets shifted from old app version to new app version. Or when I manually shift traffic to some other version.

Then is there any chances that in between shifting the traffic to the new server, can some requests fail or is it 100 percent Safe by default?

Answer (score 1):

The traffic switching feature operates at request routing level, i.e. at the time when it is decided which available instance would be receiving the request for processing. From [Migrating Traffic](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrating-traffic):

> Traffic migration switches the request routing between the versions
>   within a service of your application, moving traffic from one or more
>   versions to a single new version.

This means that it *should* theoretically be 100% safe by default. As long as the receiving instance doesn't die while processing the request, of course. Switching traffic won't affect requests already in processing.

Comment: I got the response from their side, and the traffic migration is 100 % safe but only in case for `standard env`, but not in `flex env`. See my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I posted my question on Google Cloud community and got the response

> The answer is different depending on the App Engine environment. GAE
>   Standard for example, supports gradual traffic migration wherein you
>   can enable 'warmup request' to prepare the new instances before those
>   instances serve any traffic.
>
> In contrast, GAE Flex does not support gradual traffic migration which
>   means user requests are sent to those instances before the instances
>   get created. This results to delay/latency (not an outright fail)
>   since the request has to wait until the instance gets up and running.
>   It is possible that request may fail if the request timeouts before
>   the instance is ready. See full article [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/migrating-traffic).

See full thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/rlMdARIawaE)